# Reproducable asynchronous bug found in @testing-library/react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

Unless I'm mistaken, I believe I've found a bug in how rerenders are triggered (or in this case, aren't) by the `@testing-library/react` package. I've got a codesandbox which you can download and reproduce in seconds:

https://codesandbox.io/s/asynchronous-react-redux-toolkit-bug-8sleu4?file=/README.md

As a summary for here, I've just got a redux store and I toggle a boolean value from `false` to `true` after some async activity in an on-mount `useEffect` in a component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAppDispatch } from "../hooks/useAppDispatch";
import { setMyCoolBoolean } from "../redux/slices/exampleSlice";
import AnotherComponent from "./AnotherComponent";

export default function InnerComponent() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const fetchSomeData = async () => {
    await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people");
    dispatch(setMyCoolBoolean(true));
  };

  // on mount, set some values
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSomeData();
  }, []);

  return <AnotherComponent />;
}
```

Then, in a different component, I hook into that store value with `useAppSelector` hook and then `useEffect` to do something local there (dumb example, but it illustrates my point.):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAppSelector } from "../hooks/useAppSelector";

export default function AnotherComponent() {
  const { myCoolBoolean } = useAppSelector((state) => state.example);

  const [localBoolean, setLocalBoolean] = useState(false);

  // when myCoolBoolean changes, set the local boolean state value in this component
  // somewhat a dumb example but it illustrates
  // the failure of react-testing-library
  useEffect(() => {
    // only do something in this component
    // if myCoolBoolean changes to true
    if (myCoolBoolean) {
      console.log("SET TO TRUE!");
      setLocalBoolean(myCoolBoolean);
    }
  }, [myCoolBoolean]);

  if (localBoolean) {
    return <span data-testid="NEW">I'm new</span>;
  }
  return <span data-testid="ORIGINAL">I'm original</span>;
}
```

In result, my test would like to see if the 'new' value is ever shown. Despite issuing `rerender`, you will see the test fails:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "../../src/App";
import { act } from "react-test-renderer";
import 'whatwg-fetch'

test("On mount, boolean value changes, causing our new span to show up", async () => {
  const { getByTestId, rerender } = render(<App />);
  await act(async () => {
    // expect(getByTestId("ORIGINAL")).toBeTruthy();

    // No matter how many times you call rerender here, 
    // you'll NEVER see the "NEW" test id (and thus corresponding <span> element) appear in the document
    // despite this being the case in any standard browser
    await rerender(<App />);

    // If you comment this line below out, the test passes fine. 
    // test ID "ORIGINAL" is found, but "NEW" is never found!!!!
    expect(getByTestId("NEW")).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Behaviour is totally as expected in a browser, but fails in my jest test. Can anybody guide me on how to get my test to pass? As far as I know, the code and implementations of my React components and Redux are the cleanest and best practices that are currently out there, so I'm more expecting this is a gross misunderstanding on my part of how @testing-library works, though I thought `rerender` would do the trick.

Comment: Also note these are for full integration tests, so I'm not interested in mocking anything on the redux side of things!

Comment: I'm also not too keen on using enzyme, but if that is the only way out here, then so be it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've apparently misunderstood how react-testing-library works under the hood. You don't even need to use `rerender` or `act` at all! Simply using a `waitFor` with `await` / `async` is enough to trigger the on mount logic and subsequent rendering:

```
import React from "react";
import { findByTestId, render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "../../src/App";
import { act } from "@testing-library/react-hooks/dom";
import "whatwg-fetch";

test("On mount, boolean value changes, causing our new span to show up", async () => {
  const { getByTestId, rerender, findByTestId } = render(<App />);
  // Works fine, as we would expect
  expect(getByTestId("ORIGINAL")).toBeTruthy();
  
  // simply by using 'await' here, react-testing-library must rerender somehow
  // note that 'act' isn't even used or needed either!
  await waitFor(() => getByTestId("NEW"));
});
```

Another case of "overthinking it" gone bad...